# checking the reference in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query in the table ...

```
SELECT * FROM pos_took WHERE DELETEDDATE IS NOT NULL
```

now it contains the column tookid

and I have the second query in other table ...

```
select * from pos_rook
```

Now the pos_rook table also contain the column tooktdm_bookid

so the tooktdm_bookid of the first table is foreign key to second table

Now i have to execute the first query that is ..SELECT * FROM pos_took WHERE DELETEDDATE IS NOT NULL and in it i will get the tookid also now I have to check whether those tookid lies in pos_rook table or not that is whether the result of first query tookid exists in second table tooktdm_bookid's or not please advise how to check this references in other table words please advise the Oracle query

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT * -- List here the columns you want to select
FROM pos_took AS t
INNER JOIN pos_rook AS r ON t.tookid = r.tooktdm_bookid
WHERE t.DELETEDDATE IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the INNER JOIN statement that will get all rows that match table A and table B

You could also use the 'IN' clause - [IN Clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Or you could use the 'EXISTS' clause

Comment: CAN you please post the query thT WILL BE A GREAT HELP,tHANKS IN ADVANCE